# Run a certain command when Solana test validator starts

Tags: spl-token, solana-test-validator

Good day! I am currently running a program where I wish to create an SPL token and utilize it on my frontend. However, when I start up the test validator, I wish to also be able to run a file that will create said SPL token and the associated wallet for my provider. Is there a way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to provide some genesis account files for your test validator which will create the mint and associated token account.

Here's how you can get the accounts:

```
$ solana-test-validator -r
$ spl-token create-token
Creating token A5t3wQXK1G5ymr7Naa45euNEn7cVqqo5E6BdzPWMMMYA under program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

Address:  A5t3wQXK1G5ymr7Naa45euNEn7cVqqo5E6BdzPWMMMYA
Decimals:  9

Signature: 5jytLruwiqsPu2TbforENMHJvnChmWVYgKo8W6x2NW36sTnvV6bSxLioEH96Z8E7hHjf3wXyfsprYaYp5A7qG2oZ

$ spl-token create-account A5t3wQXK1G5ymr7Naa45euNEn7cVqqo5E6BdzPWMMMYA
Creating account FTTUP1qiH3FpmqQ8eeY7JH5GYEVnFL1UFAKn1pC71UkC

Signature: xGWZUfn7PkLq6bmboJ2p7G5rYEbfnq3zVNVmzux8xeuLHAs8jyzwZVEwsr6HygSuzVosMaMCuuYnYG9UWtH3WEC

$ solana account --output json -o mint.json A5t3wQXK1G5ymr7Naa45euNEn7cVqqo5E6BdzPWMMMYA
$ solana account --output json -o account.json FTTUP1qiH3FpmqQ8eeY7JH5GYEVnFL1UFAKn1pC71UkC
```

And then use them:

```
$ solana-test-validator -r \
  --account FTTUP1qiH3FpmqQ8eeY7JH5GYEVnFL1UFAKn1pC71UkC account.json \
  --account A5t3wQXK1G5ymr7Naa45euNEn7cVqqo5E6BdzPWMMMYA mint.json
```